# Is there any other Republican who is against a TikTok ban?

Tags: united-states, republican-party, social-media

> Sen. Rand Paul (R-Ky.) said on Tuesday that the proposed TikTok ban
> “makes no sense,” ahead of an expected vote on the House floor on
> Wednesday.
>
> In an interview with NewsNation’s Leland Vitter on “On Balance,” Paul
> argued that a ban on TikTok would be akin to steps employed by the
> Chinese government, which, Paul said, is precisely the supposed threat
> from which such a ban would purport to shield Americans.
>
> “TikTok is banned in China,” Paul said. “We’re thinking – or people
> who want to ban it are thinking – Wow, we’re going to really defeat
> the Chinese communists, by becoming Chinese authoritarians and banning
> it in our country? TikTok is banned in China. So, we’re going to
> emulate the Chinese communists by banning it in our country?”
>
> “It makes no sense whatsoever,” he added.

https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/4527989-rand-paul-proposed-tiktok-ban-makes-no-sense/

Is there any other Republican who is against a TikTok ban? Rand Paul has expressed his disagreement about the proposed TikTok ban arguing that a ban of TikTok is similar to what the government of China did against U.S. social media companies. I was wondering if any other Republicans also expressed their opposition to such a move and why.

Comment: Of course, the problem with these arguments is that the bill is *not* a TikTok ban. They're OK with TikTok in general, they just want it to be owned by an American company, not one beholden to the Chinese government.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The house vote was almost two weeks ago.  Fifteen republicans [voted](https://clerk.house.gov/Votes/202486) against the TikTok ban. Many of them made statements about it. eg,

[Nancy Mace](https://mace.house.gov/media/press-releases/rep-nancy-mace-opposes-government-overreach-tiktok-ban):

> "Banning TikTok is beating the same drum as other communist countries controlling what content we are able to see," says Rep. Mace. "Let's not give the government any more power to control social media."

[Marjorie Taylor Green](https://twitter.com/RepMTG/status/1767914172895862798):

> As the only member of Congress who has ever been banned from social media, I oppose today’s TikTok ban bill.
>
> This bill would open Pandora’s box and create a slippery slope for future government censorship of Americans and our precious First Amendment.

[Tom McClintock](https://mcclintock.house.gov/newsroom/speeches/rep-mcclintock-speaks-tiktok-debate):

> The last thing we should do is take that power AWAY from the people and give it to the government.
>
> The answer to authoritarianism is NOT more authoritarianism.  The answer to CCP-style propaganda is NOT CCP-style oppression.
>
> Let us SLOW down before we BLUNDER down this very steep and slippery slope.

Former President Donald Trump is also against the ban since it might help Facebook.